# Classification of small finite distributive lattices

Tags: co.combinatorics

Is there a tabulation somewhere of the isomorphism classes of distributive lattices $L$ with $|L|=n$ for small $n$?  Google has not found me one.

Comment: You might get better results by looking for small partial orders and then invoking Birkhoff's theorem that any finite distributive lattice is (isomorphic to) the lattice of downward-closed sets in some partial order. The lattice is bigger than the order, so you might be able to use a smaller value of $n$. Unfortunately, the size of the poset doesn't determine the size of the partial order.

Comment: The number of isomorphism classes is at https://oeis.org/A006982. The references there might be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem to collect posets with certain properties and for distributive lattices I have the following solution which was good enough for my purposes.
Here is a sage program to obtain all distributive lattices (in form of their leq matrices) on $n$ points which works for $n \leq 9$ in the sage online cell https://sagecell.sagemath.org/ and works for about $n \leq 14$ with sage with a good computer (and alot of waiting).

```
n=5;
P=Posets(n-2)
P=[p.with_bounds() for p in P]
L=[p for p in P if p.is_lattice() and LatticePoset(p).is_distributive()]
display(len(L))
U=[p.lequal_matrix() for p in L]
display(U)
display(L[2])
```

the display(L[2]) command displays a distributive lattice of your choice and
the len(L) command gives the number of distributive lattices on $n$ elements.